# Same profile SonarQube ignore some rules in the new instance

Tags: java, sonarqube, rules, sonarqube-scan

I face an issue, if you can guide me please,

I have exported a QualityProfile "Sonar way" from an instance SonarQube Version 6.5 (build 27846) - LGPL v3 to be imported in the same version.

The problem is, when i want to import it, it ignore some rules,i search in the changelog to find why, is it blocked by the new instance,

[image]

If you have any idea please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to check that the installed language plugins are the same between the server instances. I see mainly 2 possible reasons to the issue you describe:

- one language plugin is only installed on the source server
- the version of a language plugin is newer on the source server than on the destination one

Comment: thanks @Mithfindel, exaclty there was a difference in the version language plugin it was hard to obtain it, because i havn't the permissions to acces admin panel.